# PHP echo dynamic radio button with variable name

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

So i have these radio buttons in XHTML that I want to put into a PHP function to generate and I can't get it to work.

In XHTML it looks like this and is working;

```
<p><input type="radio" value="<? echo blabla; ?>" name="radioA" checked="checked" /></p>
<input type="hidden" value="<? echo $value; ?>" name="hiddenA[]" />
```

In PHP I need to set the "radioA" and "hiddenA" to variables respectively "radioB"/"hiddenB", "radioC"/"hiddenC" and so on for my code to work. This is what I have so far but it is not working. The first radio name is a string, but the second one is array. Thanks in advance.

```
function radio($Radio, $Array) {
    echo '<p><input type="radio" value="$value>" name="$Radio" />', $value, '</p>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="$value" name="$Array" />';
}
```

I guess what I'm trying to do is to return the name of the variable as a string. $_POST['hiddenA'] ===> hiddenA[]

Comment: You have to use double qouted(`"`)  strings for variables in them to be expanded.

Comment: Where is the $Value coming from? "." append strings not "," in PHP. If the variable $Array is an array and you echo it it will echo an array. Perhaps you meant to access a value from the array? As a general rule you should use a lower case letter to begin a variable name: $array rather then $Array...

Comment: The problems is that I need to set up the name of the button to the name of the array, not the value of the array. So if i type it manually in XHTML name="hiddenA[]" works, but if i use PHP to echo it, it needs to be $_POST['hiddenA']. So that's where I get confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic php syntax:

```
$a = 'hello';
echo '$a'; // outputs the literal characters $ and a
echo "$a"; // outputs "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax issues here:

```
function radio($Radio, $Array) {
    echo '<p><input type="radio" value="$Value>" name="$Radio" />', $Value, '</p>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="$Value" name="$Array" />';
}
```

1. You have to use "" not '' when embedding variables:

   `echo "My name is {$name}.";`
2. In PHP the . character is used to append strings not ,

   `echo "My name is " . $name . " and I am cool";`
3. If you try to echo an array you will get the word Array not the array itself. Instead you can echo a value in the array:

   `echo "$array[0]";`
4. You are trying to use a variable that is not defined in your example: `$Value`. This would give you an VariableUndefined exception.
5. It is generally bad practice to use capital letters at the start of variable names in PHP. So `$Array` should be `$array`.

With these  in mind you code should look something like:

```
function radio($radio, $array) {
    $value1 = $array[0];
    $value2 = $array[1];

    echo "<p><input type=\"radio\" value=\"$value1>\" name=\"$radio\" />$value1</p>";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$value2\" name=\"$value2\" />";
}
```

From the sounds of your example you need a for loop somewhere.